# Get the radio button pointer from a dynamic radiogroup dialog

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button, radio-group

I have a custom radio group dialog and i am inflating it dynamically.

In my `onCreate()` I am doing this

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
alarmType1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmType);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

        radioAlarmtype = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
initRadioDialog();
```

then initializing the dialog with the following code

```
String string_Alarmtype[]={"Melody","Vibration","Melody and Vibration"};

    public void initRadioDialog()
    {
        Context context=AlarmActivity.this;
        dialog_radio=new Dialog(context);
        dialog_radio.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);
        radioAlarmtype = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // add 3 radio buttons to the group
        RadioButton rb;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            rb = new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setText(string_Alarmtype[i]);
            rb.setId(i);
            radioAlarmtype.addView(rb, layoutParams);
        }

        radioAlarmtype.check(2);
        radioAlarmtype.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                //alarmType1.setText(rb.getText());
                Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this, checkedId + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        dialog_radio.setContentView(view);
    }
```

but above commented line `//alarmType1.setText(rb.getText());`is causing a **nullpointerException**
so i tried it on my textview onClickListener
like this

```
View.OnClickListener alarmTypeListener = new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {

        dialog_radio.show();
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioAlarmtype.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        alarmType1.setText(rb.getText());//NUllpointerException here
       Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this,"HEllo"+rb.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//here also nullpointerException if I comment above line
    }

};
```

But the problem still persist so how can i change the textview as change in the selection of radio button in my dialog.

Comment: could you check whether "rb" is null?

Comment: yes its null; now how should i get the radiobutton pointer from my radio group

Comment: I think you have to write "RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) **radioAlarmType**.findViewById(checkedId);" because you added your radiobuttons to that ViewGroup

Comment: thanx i did not know it works that way. I got a totally new concept by this.